# Why does (float)1.11111111 = 1.11111116 in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point

Why does `(float)1.11111111 = 1.11111116` in C#?

Comment: Welcome to the floating point oddities :) If you do not want to struggle with it because you do not need it, use a fixed precision type, neither float nor double. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605124/fixed-point-math-in-c) may help.

Comment: To understand what data type would be the best fit for you, we would need to know what you are trying to represent with it. If you update your question I'm sure someone can then make a suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: another duplicate: [Why IEEE754 single-precision float has only 7 digit precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19130396/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a float is **NOT** an exact value: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding) explains it pretty much. Also make sure you watch [Jon Skeet's video](http://vimeo.com/7403673) from around 6:00 to 10:00. In short: Use [floats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)/[doubles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for continuous values, [decimals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)/[integers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5kzh1b5w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) etc. for discrete values.

Comment: Do you have a link to that video?

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. In understanding the problem I found these links very useful: 

http://floating-point-gui.de
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c

In conculsion I'll use decimal for when I want to do arithmetic with rational numbers.

Answer (score 9):

[Floats have 7 digit precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza(v=vs.100).aspx) and are only approximations of actual numbers; equality and other operators don't always work as *you* would expect, though they are working perfectly fine.

The obligatory link: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

[There is the `Epsilon` property on floats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.epsilon.aspx) that can be used to help mitigate very small fractional issues with float values, though I have never used it. I'll admit my experience with floating point numbers is limited.

If you need more precision, [`double` is larger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(v=vs.100).aspx) with 15-16 digit precision. If you need even more precision and specifically across base-10 numbers (such as for currency calculations), use `decimal`.

Comment: And best precision is decimal, with 28 Digit precision :)

Comment: @Marcel1997 Yeah I need to correct this, `decimal` is not integral, it is actually a decimal floating point as opposed to binary floating point number.