# C++ accounting application floating point to fixed point

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a c++ ledger application in which floating point is used for calculations, now what should I do to convert to fix point arthimatic (considerably upto 4 digits past decimal point) without generating more bugs in the program. Any step wise process which I should adopt or tips to prevent errors? Please suggest some test cases which will be helpful

Comment: Creating a suite of unit tests to cover all the current calculations in your application would be a good start. It would be a good to be able to swap between fixed and floating point easily in this scenario, so that you can compare results easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Introduce a type `Currency` used in relevant computations (if not done already)
2. Make sure all relevant numbers are stored as `Currency`, not as `double`, or `float`
3. Define `Currency` with a fixed-point real type. You can use existing implementations, like [CodeF00's `numeric::Fixed`](http://codef00.com/coding). See also [What's the best way to do fixed-point math?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79677/whats-the-best-way-to-do-fixed-point-math)

Comment: Please suggest tests and tips to avoid performance issues as well.:)

Comment: I looked at your reference, sorry to be naive but it says that according to your architecture(bitsize) you can typedef fixed class. For eg typedef fixed<16,16> fixed. 
Will it affect if I shift my data to different architectures.Any way to keep it uniform.

Comment: Test tips are very application-specific. Cannot say anything non-obvious having no information on your case. Concerning your second comment - don't hesitate to use question marks.

Comment: Well I have used GMP lib for a double entry ledger system. I agree that you  will need to know more features of the system to describe the tests. But a test which proves whether error exist due to current floating point arthimatic will be fine. I wanted tips on how is performance affected if i use  fixed point arithematic on top of GMP vs MPFR of GMP.